# How to programmatically determine the number of nodes in a Cassandra Cluster?

Tags: c, cassandra, thrift, cassandra-2.0

Is there a way to determine the number of nodes in a Cassandra cluster without first having a context?

I am trying to get that number to make sure that the user does not give me a replicating factor that is too large (i.e. says 10 with only 9 nodes.)

**Important:** At this point, the only interface I have is thrift in C.

**Note:** I looked into using the describe_ring() but unfortunately, the function forces you to have a valid context (so it describes the ring for that context and not the number of existing nodes in a Cassandra cluster.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at the system table using the Thrift protocol:  **system.peers**. Here are listed **all others nodes** and their information, but not the local node. By counting the number of nodes in **system.peers**, the total node count is entries_count_in_peers + 1

Below is the structure (CQL) of the **system.peers** table

```
CREATE TABLE system.peers (
    peer inet PRIMARY KEY,
    data_center text,
    host_id uuid,
    preferred_ip inet,
    rack text,
    release_version text,
    rpc_address inet,
    schema_version uuid,
    tokens set<text>
)
```

There is one **partition** (row key in Thrift terminology) per node

Comment: Ah! I see it now. I have a node using Cassandra 1.1.5 where it does not exist yet. But in Cassandra 2.0.1 it is there. Great! 8-)

Comment: Well... somehow thrift does not seem to be able to see that peers table. I guess it has to be done with CQL on that one. I will have to postpone that feature for now.

Comment: Relying on peers table can be error prone as I have observed this table sometimes has some extra ip as well eg: private ip of same node on cassandra 2.1.16 cluster...Any other way to progmmatically getting the correct number of nodes in the cluster ? may be parsing the output of nodetool satus ?